# PTIJ: Where is last year's child?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Last year, 5779 was a שנה מעוברת - a pregnant  year. If the year became pregnant in Tishrei, then, I would expect that we would have seen its child around Sivan 5779.

It's way past that point, and I haven't seen the  year's kid. What happened to it?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: התשעט means to hit one's self, as in Jer. 47:3, so it must have miscarried. :(

Comment: Have you tried being jealous of a סופר?

Comment: @Rish I don't understand the relevance of your question. Personally, jealousy isn't part of my character, other than kealousy of Torah knowledge and someone else's exemplary character. As a *ba'al kri'a*, I have high admiration and tremendous respect for *Sofrim*. It's a very difficult craft that is severely underpaid.

Comment: "Jealousy of Torah knowledge and someone else's exemplary character." That's what I meant :-) קנאת סופרים תרבה חכמה, and what you're asking for is to be רואה את הנולד, which apparently is only doable by a high-level חכם, as it says, איזהו חכם הרואה את הנולד. I would have put it as an answer, but I was trying to play off the standard Stack Exchange clarifying-questions-in-the-comments thing.

Answer (score 8):

5779 became pregnant in the second month of Adar, and so a birth would have been expected nine months later, in Cheshvan 5780. But by that time, the season was already fall, from which we can infer that the year caused fall, or rather הפילה (miscarried).

Answer (score 0):

When he’s 13, you can be sure to hear him called up as בן שלש עשרה. Until then, he’ll lay low as he’s only about בן שנה.